# The position of complex points on the kiwi-graph of the Jones polynomial

Tags: cv.complex-variables, knot-theory, jones-polynomial

Consider the "kiwi" graph below (the name came from the resemblance to the bird, the national symbol of New Zealand, the country of V. Jones) i.e., roots of the Jones polynomial for knots (up to 15 crossing number) in the complex plane with the additional unit circle drawn.

[image]

There are well-known centers of the white "holes" in the unit circle, compare [this topic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176862/the-jones-polynomial-at-specific-values-of-t). I am interested in the centers of the (visible here) white holes, not on the unit circle. Does anyone know what their algebraic (not approximate) coordinates are (or some of them)?

Comment: Is this [just](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Algebraic_integers.gif) because the roots of Jones polynomials are algebraic integers?