# Coloured Jones polynomial at 4th root of unity and Arf invariant

Tags: knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, quantum-topology, jones-polynomial

Looking at the link invariants of $\operatorname{SU}(2)$ Chern-Simons theory, if we take the coloured Jones polynomial of a knot K, say $J_N^K$ at fundamental representation $N=2$, then we get the usual Jones Polynomial which when evaluated at $i$, the 4th root of unity, is equal to the Arf invariant as per the bottom of this [page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArfInvariant.html). So the Jones polynomial will have value $0$ or $1$. This agrees with the Theorem 19 of this [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1985-12-01/S0273-0979-1985-15304-2/S0273-0979-1985-15304-2.pdf).

On the other hand if we look at the answer to this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176862/the-jones-polynomial-at-specific-values-of-t) and it's comment, where we take number of components to be $1$ for the link to be a knot, then the Jones polynomial takes the values $1$ or $-1$, depending on on the Arf invariant being $0$ or $1$, when evaluated at $i$. This is actually in agreement with the fact that if I consider the trefoil knot with Jones polynomial $t+t^3-t^4$ then at $t = i$ we get $-1$.
So where is the discrepancy coming from?

More generally, is there any reference or understanding of the coloured Jones polynomial when evaluated at $i$ for other representations? For $N=1$ its just the trivial representation so $J_1^K(t)=1$ for any $t$. For $N=2$ at $i$, its the standard Jones polynomial so is $J_2^K(t)|_{t=i} =$ $0$ or $1$, or, $= 1$ or $-1$ (up to discrepancy). Very specifically, what about for $N=3$ at $i$, i.e., $J_3^K(t)|_{t=i}$?

Comment: There's no discrepancy for $N=2$: Theorem 19 in Jones' paper is about W (Definition 17) and not V (which is the usual Jones polynomial).